# Split features into multiple tiles

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

With tileset-cli I create a tileset. Add to the map. Displays features correctly. But when I click, I get the coordinates of not the whole polygon, but only its parts. I.e. when zoom in features are divided into several tiles. How can this be prohibited? That every feature is always one polygon, without division?